# How can i implement multi template in cakephp

Tags: templates, cakephp

I use the CakePHP framework and I want to have multiple templates in my project.
Is there any way for implementation of multiple templates in CakePHP?

For example, an admin can choose first the or second template in the backend and users can use the same template. (Like in the Joomla backend). If there is any way, how can I implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just giving you basic idea about how you can do that.

In app_controller try below code.

```
<?php
class AppController extends Controller
{
    var $components = array( 'Auth','Session', 'RequestHandler','Email','Gzip.Gzip','SwiftMailer');

    var $helpers = array( 'Javascript', 'Form', 'Html', 'Session','Time','Custom','Paginator','Text' );

    function beforeFilter()
    {
        if(isset($this->params['admin']) && $this->params['admin'] == 1)
        {
            $this->layout = "admin";
        }
        else
        {
            $this->layout = "default";
        }       
    }
?>
```

And inside other controller file which extends app_controller add you must have code as below.

```
<?php
class OtherController extends Controller
{
    var public $uses = array('ModelName');

    function beforeFilter()
    {
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }
?>
```

**You can also overwrite `$this->layout` to every controller action.**

Answer (score 1):

You can create different templates in `View/layouts`

`template_1.ctp`, `template_2.ctp` with different styles

And create the `default.ctp` layout which will include one of the existing templates or set `$this->layout = 'template_1';` in the `AppController`;

```
<?php
    //default.ctp
    $loadTemplate = 'template_1.ctp';//value from database or config file?
    include_once($loadTemplate);
?>
```

Or you could use themes as per [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/themes.html)

Comment: include / require should not be used for loading templates.